# CSS Menu moving links left on hover

Tags: html, css

i have this CSS:

```
#menu {
    float:right;
}
#menu > ul > li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:20px;
}
#menu > ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color:#CCC;
}
```

and this HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div><!-- menu -->
```

but when i hover over a link the links are moving to the left - any ideas?

Comment: I think we need more of your html and css. when I try the example given it is fine.  My guess is that you have another :hover in your css that is changing the `padding`.

Comment: your example works withouth any moving: http://jsfiddle.net/WgmgF/ - please create a fiddle with your problem

Comment: some other css that is probably linked to your li items is causing it. need the entire css to tell what is causing the shift.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
#menu {
    float:right;
}
#menu > ul > li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:20px;
}
#menu > ul > li > a:hover {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    color:#CCC;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu > ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color:#CCC;
    float: right !important;
}
```

This should work